# Splitting numbers and letters from a string misses zeroes

Tags: powershell

I am processing a time value that arrives in a string that starts with a `T` then is followed by a series of numbers immediately followed by the unit for each number. For example, 8 hours and 22 minutes will come in as `T8H22M` and 3 hours, 2 minutes, and 1 second will be `T3H2M1S`.

I need to split this encoded value into separate H/M/S columns, but I am having issues getting zeroes to work properly. I am using this code from another Question here with similar (but not identical) requirements.

This script:

```
Write-Host $('T8H22M' -split { [bool]($_ -as [double]) })
Write-Host $('T8H22M' -split { ! [bool]($_ -as [double]) })
Write-Host $('T8H0M' -split { [bool]($_ -as [double]) })
Write-Host $('T8H0M' -split { ! [bool]($_ -as [double]) })
Write-Host $('T0H' -split { $_ -eq '0' })
```

Produces this output:

```
T H  M
 8 22 
T H0M
 8   
T H
```

As you can see, any time the numerical value is zero the string just doesn't split.  This is a real problem as zero-time comes in as `T0H` which just won't parse using the method above.

How can I modify the code above to also split out zero values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compliment the answers from [@boxdog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9529842/boxdog) and [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) on the actual question *why* the zero's are missing and ***"How can I modify the code above to also split out zero values?"***

Quote on the `<ScriptBlock>` parameter

> **`<ScriptBlock>`**
> An expression that specifies rules for applying the delimiter. The
> expression must evaluate to `$true` or `$false`. Enclose the script block
> in braces.

The point here is that the `0` evaluates to `$False` ("[`falsy`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/boolean-values-and-operators/)"):

```
if (0) { 'True' } else { 'False' }
False

if (1) { 'True' } else { 'False' }
True

[Bool]0
False

[Bool]1
True
```

In other words you will need to compare your split expression against `$Null` to get what you are looking for:

```
Write-Host $('T8H22M' -split { $Null -ne ($_ -as [double]) })
T H  M
Write-Host $('T8H22M' -split { $Null -eq ($_ -as [double]) })
 8 22
Write-Host $('T8H0M' -split { $Null -ne ($_ -as [double]) })
T H M
Write-Host $('T8H0M' -split { $Null -eq ($_ -as [double]) })
 8 0
```

Anyways, I recommend you to go for the solution from @boxdog or @Theo.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to use the ISO8601 conversion as it is the best method, but this is the correct answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex to extract the values.  For example:

```
'T3H2M1S','T8H22M','T8H0M','T0H' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match '^T((?<hours>\d+)H)*((?<minutes>\d+)M)*((?<seconds>\d+)S)*$') {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                TimeString = $matches.0
                Hours      = [Int]$matches.hours
                Minutes    = [Int]$matches.minutes
                Seconds    = [Int]$matches.seconds
            }
        }
    }
```

This produces an object for each time string, with `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` properties corresponding to the related part of that string:

```
TimeString Hours Minutes Seconds
---------- ----- ------- -------
T3H2M1S        3       2       1
T8H22M         8      22       0
T8H0M          8       0       0
T0H            0       0       0
```

Of course, you can change the contents of the `if` to manipulate the values however you like, not just creating an object - the key is that the RegEx should* split it correctly for you.

**** - I say 'should' because I only tested with the example strings you give, so be sure to test more thoroughly yourself.***

Answer (score 3):

The time values you have resemble the [ISO 8601 duration format](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_duration_format.htm) except they all lack the leading `P`.

You can use the `ToTimeSpan()` method of .net `System.Xml.XmlConvert` to convert these to TimeSpans using:

```
'T3H2M1S','T8H22M','T8H0M','T0H' | ForEach-Object { 
    [System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("P$_")  # prepend a 'P'
}
```

To return an array of TimeSpan objects

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 8
Minutes           : 22
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 301200000000
TotalDays         : 0,348611111111111
TotalHours        : 8,36666666666667
TotalMinutes      : 502
TotalSeconds      : 30120
TotalMilliseconds : 30120000

Days              : 0
Hours             : 8
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 288000000000
TotalDays         : 0,333333333333333
TotalHours        : 8
TotalMinutes      : 480
TotalSeconds      : 28800
TotalMilliseconds : 28800000

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 0
TotalDays         : 0
TotalHours        : 0
TotalMinutes      : 0
TotalSeconds      : 0
TotalMilliseconds : 0
```

Now you can use any of the properties to format as you like.